# how to read and process large zip files in node-js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to read a large zip file in node-js and process each file (approx 100MB zip file containing ca 40.000 XML files, 500kb each file uncompressed). I am looking for a 'streaming' solution that has acceptable speed and does not require to keep the whole dataset in memory (JSZip, node-zip worked for me, but it keeps everything in RAM and the performance is not good enough). A quick attempt in c# shows that loading, unpacking and parsing the XML can be achieved in approx 9 seconds on 2 year old laptop (using `DotNetZip`). I don't expect nodejs to be as fast, but anything under one minute would be okay. Unpacking the file to local disk and then processing it, is not an option.

I am currently attempting to use the `unzip` module (https://www.npmjs.org/package/unzip) but can't get it work, so I don't know if the speed is okay, but at least it looks like I can stream each file and process it in the callback. (The problem is that I only receive the first 2 entries, then it stops calling the `.on('entry', callback)` callback. I don't get any error, it just silently stops after 2 files. It would also be good to know how I can get the full XML in one chunk instead of fetching buffer after buffer.)

```
    function openArchive(){
      fs.createReadStream('../../testdata/small2.zip')
        .pipe(unzip.Parse())
        .on('entry', function (entry) {
            var fileName = entry.path;
            var type = entry.type; // 'Directory' or 'File'
            var size = entry.size;
            console.log(fileName);
            entry.on('data', function(data){
              console.log("received data");
            });
        });
    }
```

There's plenty of node-js modules for working with zip files, so this question is really about to figure out which library is best suited for this scenario.

Comment: When you say you "can't get it to work" - what issue?  what error?  It's hard for others to troubleshoot that general statement.

Comment: I mentioned what doesn't work. The code above only reads two files from a zip.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same task to do: process 100+ MB zip archives with 100 000+ XML files in each of them. In that case, unzipping the files on disk is just a waste of HD space. I tried adm-zip but it would load and expand the whole archive in RAM, and my script would break at around 1 400 MB RAM usage.

Using the code from the question, and the nice tip from Dilan's answer,  I was sometimes only getting partial XML content, that would of course break my XML parser.

After some trials, I've ended up with that code:

```
// process one .zip archive
function process_archive(filename) {
    fs.createReadStream(filename)
        .pipe(unzip.Parse())
        .on('entry', function (entry) {
            // entry.path is file name
            // entry.type is 'Directory' or 'File'
            // entry.size is size of file
            const chunks = [];
            entry.on('data',  (data) => chunks.push(data));
            entry.on('error', (err)  => console.log(err));
            entry.on('end', () => {
                let content = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8');
                process_my_file(entry.path, content);
                entry.autodrain();
            });
        });

    return;
}
```

If this can help anybody, it's quite fast and worked well for me, only using a max of 25 MB of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

you have to call .autodrain() or pipe data to another stream

```
entry.on('data', function(data) {
    entry.autodrain();
    // or entry.pipe(require('fs').createWriteStream(entry.path))
});
```