# JavaScript: Extracting large archive causes crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, zip, archive

I work on a react project that integrates Potree to display large point clouds in an online viewer.
I'm stuck on the part where the administrators should upload to the server a new point cloud.

A point cloud for Potree is basically a folder with inside a HTML file and nested folders containing all the needed files for the point cloud.

Typical point cloud folder structure for Potree

testPointCloud
L testPointCloud.html
L pointclouds
L testPointCloud
L hierarchy.bin
L log.txt
L metadata.json
L octree.bin

File octree.bin contains the actual point cloud and can be quite large (**usually 500 MB to 1.5 GB**)

My idea is that the administrator will zip the testPointCloud root folder and upload it to the server via a dedicated back-office page. This part works fine.

The server (Express framework for Node.js) receives the correctly the archive via API. But I fail to correctly extract the archive.
If I upload the archive as a .ZIP, the decompression will stop once it arrives at the "octree.bin" file, ignoring the other files of the archives.
If I upload the archive as a .TAR, I can extract the archive properly, but during the extraction my Express server will stop and resume once the extration as completed.

Here is my code for the extraction that got me the closest to my goal:

```
const decompress = require('decompress');

exports.createPointCloud = (req, res, next) => {
    const fileName = req.file.filename.split('.')[0].replace(/[^a-z0-9_.\-\s]/gi, '_').replace(/\s+/g, '_');

    decompress(req.file.path, "potree/" + fileName).then(files => {
        // I add the point cloud to the database here
    });
 };
```

I tried with different libraries to manage the archives (such as adm-zip or decompress), but I have similar results.
Reading some similar questions (like [how to read and process large zip files in node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684437/how-to-read-and-process-large-zip-files-in-node-js)), I seems to understand that I should use stream feature and pipe methode to avoid eating all the RAM ressources of my server, but I can't figure how to use that.

Note that I'm a total amater dev, and this is a personnal project. It is possible that I'm going totally in the wrong direction to manage the upload of the point clouds. In this case, thank you to head me to the right direction.

Regards;